I want to combine two PromQL queries into one table - Grafana
I have two queries. One is counting the number of pods with specific label from K8s datasource and the other one is displaying a gauge from application datasource.
they both have namespace as a common value
sum(metric1{}) by (kubernetes_namespace)
count(kube_pod_container_resource_limits{container=~“container_name.*”,resource=“cpu”}) by ( namespace)

I want the table to look like
namespace number_of_pods metric_1
X Y Z

Note: I was able to get the format by using the following transformations.
Time series to table
Concatenate fields
Group by
kubernetes_namespace Group_by
namespace Ignored
Trend A calculate last
Trend B calculate last

The problem is that I want to export this table as CSV and the cell type Sparkline is not being exported. I want to have the display as a normal table.

Found solution. If I change the query type from Time Series to Table , I get the 2 queries as 2 tables side by side. Then I can concatenate and group by to get the table I want...
